# Place specific programs in virtual memory / swap memory

Tags: google-chrome, memory, swap

I was just curious if it was possible to identify programs that I want to be swapped and others that I want to keep in ram.
For example, I've realized that Chrome sometimes takes up to 2GB of RAM and I would definitely enjoy swapping all the instances since they are not big on computational resources.

Comment: On what OS?....

Comment: You can try but it would provide worst performance than you might think the os will do a much better job than any script or program might do

Comment: Windows primarily